# Using FOR and DO IF NOT EXIST to check files in folder and its ANY subfolders

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, if-statement

Trying to write a very simple batch. The batch checks if there is special criteria kind of files of one location anywhere in other location, and if so DOES NOT copy duplicated files there. Problem is that I want to check file existence not only in DESTINATION folder, but in ANY subfolders of that destination folder. I can use several IF NOT EXIST c:\destination\folder1 IF NOT EXIST c:\destination\folder2 IF NOT EXIST c:\destination\folder3 … etc. But there may be newly created subfolders with names I cannot predict in batch. So how can I extend checking FOR / DO IF NOT EXIST in destination folder and its subfolders?

There is working batch only for DESTINATION folder itself.

```
FOR %%a IN (c:\source\01????.txt) ^
DO IF NOT EXIST "c:\destination\%%~nxa" ^
COPY "c:\source\%%~nxa" "c:\destination\%%~nxa"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`if [not] exist`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) accepts a certain path only. However, you could use the [`dir` command](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) together with its `/S` option, surpress the (error) output and query the returned exit code by [`&&`/`||`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), which is `0` if the item has been found and non-zero (`1`) if it has not:

```cmd
for %%A in ("C:\source\01????.txt") do (
    dir /S /B /A:-D "C:\destination\%%~nxA" > nul 2>&1 || (
        copy "%%~A" "C:\destination\%%~nxA"
    )
)
```

I also recommend to generally change your syntax style by avoiding line continuation (`^` at the end of the line) and using parentheses (`(`, `)`) instead. Besides worse readability of your style, it could happen that a certain character becomes escaped unintentionally, because the `^` at line end does actually not escape the line-break, but it lets `cmd` ignore a line-break (if there is any) and escapes the following character.
Nevertheless, if you want to stick to your style, you should make sure that the following line begins with at least one <kbd>SPACE</kbd> character.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and advice! I will follow recommendations! But for now I cannot get anything from your script. It looks like this is a right direction of logic and CMD shows some output, but nothing is copied. I tried thus and otherwise, but destination folder keeps silence. Any ideas?